# Zebra RW 420 not printing last or first inch using ZPL

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

Zebra RW 420 not printing  last or first inch(depending on rotation) using ZPL.

this [link](https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=answeropen&type=open&searchid=1419108861970&answerid=16777221&iqaction=5&url=https%3A%2F%2Fkm.zebra.com%2Fkb%2Findex%3Fpage%3Dcontent%26id%3DSO7036%26actp%3Dsearch%26viewlocale%3Den_US&highlightinfo=6292248,11,20#) was suppose to give a solution since it is the same symptom; but I've try all combinations of  "Back Feed" (~JSN, ~JSA, ~JSB) with no results.

here is my ZPL code(generated from ZebraDesigner print to file command) It doesn't print "Hello 22" completely:

```
^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNM^MTT^POI^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR2,2~SD10^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ
^XA
^MMT
^PW812
^LL2233
^LS0

^FO272,76^A0N,56,55^FH\^FDHello 11^FS
^FO320,2000^A0N,56,55^FH\^FDHello 22^FS

^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ
```

Comment: maybe it has something to do with the fact that in this model ZPL is emulated?

Comment: The emulated ZPL should not be an issue.  Start by making sure you have the printer in the correct mode for the media, black mark or gap.  Use an autoexec file to set this parameter.  Then ensure the printer is calibrated correctly by sending ^XA^JUS^XZ.  You will know the printer is calibrated correctly if you press feed and then only one full label feeds.  Lastly review line one of your code so you know what settings are being sent.  Remove anything that's not required.  Review the rest of the label code and again remove anything that inst required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem with the help of Zebra support.

The actual problem was the var **"zpl.label_length"** that was set to 2014 instead of 2233; the ^LL command is ignored in this printer and the label length is controlled only by **"zpl.label_length"**.
It printed the whole label(11")after sending the command:

```
! U1 setvar "zpl.label_length" "2233"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems with print output.  I ended up abandoning use of ^FO and went with ^FT, and everything has been perfect since.  I don't know why ^FO is so temperamental, but ^FT is very straightforward. You get what you expect.

I'd suggest getting rid of that entire first row that ZebraDesigner made. You don't need it.